# EventSetter doesn't fire for ListView if ItemContainerStyle is style

Tags: wpf, triggers, styles, mouseevent, listviewitem

A relative n00b to WPF. I have a `ListView` thus:

```xml
<ListView>
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            ...
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
    <ListView.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
            <EventSetter Event="MouseDoubleClick" Handler="ItemDoubleClick"/>
        </Style>
    </ListView.Resources>
</ListView>
```

And in my app.xaml I have the following styles:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ListView}">
    <Setter Property="ItemContainerStyle" Value="{DynamicResource ListViewItemStyle}"/>
</Style>
<Style x:Key="ListViewItemStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListViewItem">
                <Border x:Name="Border" Padding="4">
                    <GridViewRowPresenter x:Name="ItemText" 
                                          TextBlock.FontSize="14" TextBlock.Foreground="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlDarkDarkBrush}"
                                          VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" />
                </Border>

                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <MultiTrigger>
                        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True"/>
                            <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="False"/>
                        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>

                        <Setter TargetName="ItemText" Property="TextBlock.Foreground" Value="{x:Static SystemColors.WindowTextBrush}"/>
                    </MultiTrigger>

                    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrush}"/>
                        <Setter TargetName="ItemText" Property="TextBlock.Foreground" Value="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrush}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

But once I'm setting the `ItemContainerStyle`, the double-click no longer fires. If I remove it, it fires but my `ListViewItem`s are not styled.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your local resource is overridden by the application resources style which changes the ListView's ItemContainerStyle property. I would suggest setting the style directly on the `ListView.ItemContainerStyle` and basing the style on the existing one:

```
<ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}"
           BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ListViewItem}}">
        <EventSetter Event="MouseDoubleClick" Handler="ItemDoubleClick"/>
    </Style>
</ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
```

(*This assumes implicit styling, so either remove the key of the style in your application resources or reference it directly using that key in the `BasedOn` property*)

Answer (score 0):

To expand on H.B.'s answer, an element can either have an implicit Style or you can set it's Style property directly (what I call an explicit Style), but not both. As soon as you set the Style property on say a ListViewItem, it will no longer use any implicit Styles you have.

Since the ListView.ItemContainerStyle is just an easy way to set the ListViewItem.Style property, it has the same effect of short-circuiting the implicit Style you have defined.

Comment: My understanding is styles have precedence the "closer" they are to the element, but this helps me understand why it isn't necessarily so. Thank you.

Comment: @Michael - That is true for implicit Styles. Elements will search up the visual/logical tree and use the first implicit Style found. But the Style property on the element trumps all implicit Styles.